# Can't play HTML5 video

Tags: html

I am having trouble making an HTML5 video play. It wont play in any browser and in Firefox, it says "no video with supported format and MIME type found". I have read several places that say to change the htaccess file on the server which I have done by adding:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/webm .weba
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
```

at the top of the file, but the problem is still there...

Here is the HTML code:

```
               <video controls="" width="944" height="416">
                    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/julebord2.mp4"></source>
                    <source type="video/webm" src="video/julebord2.webm"></source>
                    <source type="video/ogg" src="video/julebord2.ogv"></source>
                    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
               </video>
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Are the paths to your videos definitely correct? I don't think you require the closing SOURCE tags. Try having just the word 'controls' or controls="controls". This link also might help: http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5-extension-for-wmp-plugin

Comment: Did you try to drag the *ogv*-file directly onto FireFox? Does it play the file? Maybe it's just broken.

Comment: i got it to work, turned out the file was messed up, thanks guys!